# How to import Rust library folder in my C# Program?

Tags: c#, rust

I want to use certain functions from a Rust library file but as you can see they require another file's data (`config` and a lot of others inside. The files are in the lib folder).

```
pub fn create(config: &Config, path: &Path) -> Result<()> {
if config.verbose {
    info!("Creating new empty Mod Pack at {}.", path.to_string_lossy().to_string());
}

match &config.game {
    Some(game) => {
        let mut file = BufWriter::new(File::create(path)?);
        let mut pack = Pack::new_with_version(game.pfh_version_by_file_type(PFHFileType::Mod));
        pack.encode(&mut file, &None)?;
        Ok(())
    }
    None => Err(anyhow!("No Game provided.")),
}
```

}

So how do I use this function in my c# program?

Comment: You can't just "include" a file in a completely different language. You'll have to make the Rust library provide a C ABI (using `extern "C"`), compile that into a library, then make your C# code link against that, like it would link against any other C library.

Comment: Define an `extern "cdecl" fn` in Rust, build your crate as a library ("cdylib", "staticlib") and link you library to your C# project

Comment: I see. I never used Rust so can you explain to me how I can use `extern "cdecl" fn` in my library? There are many files in this lib, where should I define it? @Miiao

Comment: I forgot to say that you need to add `#[no_mangle]` attribute before declaration of a function that you’re going to export in C#. You should define it wherever you want, just make sure you’re gonna link your library to your C# binary, or use something like dlopen. Your export signatures are going to look like ```#[no_mangle] extern "cdecl" fn name(args) -> type {body}```

Comment: Understood !! Now my last question is that the functions I want to use require objects in the condition from another file's data (as you can see above `config`, `verbose`, `game`).
How do I use the function above with the parameters needed? @Miiao

Comment: Sorry, i didn’t really understand what you meant. If you wanna pass an instance of a C# object to Rust, declare same type in Rust. Make sure you use correct data structure and layout (`#[repr(C)]`, for example). Then call your function just as a regular C (C, not C#) function. Note that Rust’s and C#’s standard data structures may differ (for example, string types). Btw maybe there are some tools for creating bindings for C# on crates.io, check it out.

Comment: @Miiao No. The function in the question is from the Rust library (guest library) and I want to use it in my c# program (host).  I don't know what parameters to use (`Config` , `Path`) in the `pub fn create(config: &Config, path: &Path)` function in my host program.